# Make a slide show by fading in background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to turn the banner image [on this page](http://preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP) into a slide show. I know how to write HTML and CSS but I'm less adept at scripting.

My idea is to have the text stay in place while the the banner image behind it is replaced. I would like to see the new image fade in.

How can I implement this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: I need the text to stay in one place whilst the image changes in the background, thanks anyway

Comment: If you don't know jQuery and you don't have time, I'm afraid you're screwed. But you can still try one of the [many jQuery slideshow plugins out there](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#qscrl=1&q=jquery+slideshow+or+carousel+plugin). Still text is achieved with a simple `position:absolute` to place it over the slideshow.

Comment: No i know, its what ive been given so all minor adjustments will be sorted last, thanks for the heads up though, just need to get this slider working

Comment: Just a fade in effect is all i was looking for, and for the text not to be effected

Comment: Do you know how to add a script to the page?

Comment: Yes, either internal or externally

Comment: Do you have URLs for the images you want to use in the slide show?

Comment: (preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/Header.png)
(preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/basecamp009.jpg)
(preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/biohazard007.jpg)
(preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/castle-storming.jpg)

Comment: Those images have different sizes. Do you plan to crop them to the same size? The last one is especially small. I don't see how you can use it.

Comment: yes ill be changing the sizes, but at the moment ill just use background-size: cover;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I implemented a simple fade-out/fade-in slide show for you. The demonstration below uses the three large files you specified in your comments. The slide show won't work until the images have been loaded, so you may want to work on improving the load times.

To use this slide show in your project, merge the CSS rules below into your CSS file, then insert the JavaScript into your page and modify the parameters `slideDelay`, `fadeLength`, and `imageSources` to suit your needs.

```js
SlideShow = {
  slideDelay: 5,  // Number of seconds to wait before showing a new slide.
  fadeLength: 1,  // Number of seconds to spend fading in or fading out.
  hertz: 60     // Number of times per second to update the fade effect.
};

SlideShow.imageSources = [
  'http://preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/basecamp009.jpg',
  'http://preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/biohazard007.jpg',
  'http://preview.impactdesigns-ad.com/HBP/img/Header.png'
];

SlideShow.showSlide = function (newImage, oldImage) {
  var g = SlideShow,
      opacityIncrement = 1 / g.hertz,
      fade = { interval: {}, count: {} };
  function fadeOut() {  // Gradually makes the old image vanish.
    oldImage.style.opacity = fade.count.out * opacityIncrement;
    if (--fade.count.out == 0) {
      window.clearInterval(fade.interval.out);
      oldImage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }
  function fadeIn() {  // Gradually makes the new image appear.
    newImage.style.opacity = 1 - fade.count.in * opacityIncrement;
    if (--fade.count.in == 0) {
      window.clearInterval(fade.interval.in);
    }
  }
  function newSlide() {  // Starts the fade-in process.
    newImage.style.opacity = 0;
    newImage.style.visibility = 'visible';
    fade.count.in = g.hertz;
    fade.interval.in = window.setInterval(fadeIn, g.fadeLength * 1000 / g.hertz);
  }
  if (oldImage) {  // Fade out the old, then fade in the new.
    window.setTimeout(newSlide, g.fadeLength * 1000);
    fade.count.out = g.hertz;
    fade.interval.out = window.setInterval(fadeOut, g.fadeLength * 1000 / g.hertz);
  } else {  // If there is no old image, immediately fade in the new image.
    newSlide(); 
  } 
}   

SlideShow.replaceSlide = function () {  // Updates slideIndex and calls showSlide.
  var g = SlideShow,
      images = g.images,
      oldImage = images[g.slideIndex];
  g.slideIndex = ++g.slideIndex % images.length;
  var newImage = images[g.slideIndex];
  g.showSlide(newImage, oldImage);
};
    
SlideShow.stop = function () { 
  var g = SlideShow,
      interval = g.interval;
  window.clearInterval(interval);
}       

SlideShow.start = function () {
  var g = SlideShow,
      imageSources = g.imageSources,
      images = g.images = [],
      container = document.getElementById('slideContainer'),
      background = g.background = document.createElement('div');
  background.className = 'background';
  for (var i = 0; i < imageSources.length; ++i) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = imageSources[i];
    image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    images.push(image);
    background.appendChild(image);
  }
  container.appendChild(background);
  var startInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
      if (images[i].height == 0) {  // Wait until all images are loaded.
        return;
      }
    }
    window.clearInterval(startInterval);
    g.slideIndex = 0;
    g.showSlide(images[g.slideIndex]);
    g.interval = window.setInterval(g.replaceSlide, g.slideDelay * 1000);
  }, 100);
};

SlideShow.start();
```

```css
#slideContainer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #cb4949;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#slideContainer span {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#slideContainer .background, #slideContainer .background img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideContainer"> <span>This is some text over the slide.</span> </div>

<button onclick="SlideShow.stop()"> stop slide show </button>
```

Comment: I have down voted this. Its a good effort but this is not what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about answering questions. I answered the question. I don't understand why you're downvoting a proper answer.